# Angular/Keycloak: Component Load before AuthGuard triggers

Tags: angular, keycloak

I currently have the problem that my components are loaded and can be seen shortly in the browser before the "canActivate" with my AuthGuard is triggered and the redirect to the Keycloak login is done.

I currently made an own directory for my Keycloak-related stuff. There I have a KeycloakAuthService that looks like this:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class KeycloakAuthService {
  constructor(private keycloakService: KeycloakService, private configService: ConfigService) {}

  init(): Promise<boolean|void> {
    const keycloakConfig = {
      url: this.configService.keycloakUrl,
      realm: this.configService.keycloakRealm,
      clientId: this.configService.keycloakClientId,
    };

    const keycloakInitOptions: KeycloakInitOptions = {
      onLoad: 'login-required',
      flow: 'standard'
    };

    const keycloakOptions: KeycloakOptions = {
      config: keycloakConfig,
      initOptions: keycloakInitOptions,
      enableBearerInterceptor: true,
      bearerExcludedUrls: ['/assets'],
      bearerPrefix: 'Bearer',
    }

    return this.keycloakService
      .init(keycloakOptions)
      .then((auth) => {
        console.log('[KeycloakAuthService] Keycloak Initialized', auth);
        return auth;
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error('[KeycloakAuthService] Error initializing Keycloak', err);
      });
  }

  # Further code here
```

Next to this I have a file "keycloak-initializer.ts" that looks like the following:

```
export function keycloakInitializer(keycloak: KeycloakAuthService) {
  return () => keycloak.init();
}
```

Then, in the app.module.ts I add the APP_INITIALIZER:

```
...
providers: [
    ...,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: keycloakInitializer,
      deps: [KeycloakAuthService],
      multi: true,
    }
  ],
...
```

I also have a AuthGuard, that looks like the following:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard extends KeycloakAuthGuard {
  constructor(
    protected override readonly router: Router,
    protected readonly keycloak: KeycloakService
  ) {
    super(router, keycloak);
  }

  public async isAccessAllowed(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ) {
    // Force the user to log in if currently unauthenticated.
    if (!this.authenticated) {
      await this.keycloak.login({
        redirectUri: window.location.origin + state.url
      });
    }

    return this.authenticated;
  }
}
```

And that is used for my routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'contracts',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },
  {
    path: 'contracts',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('@my-ui/contract/feature-contract-list').then(
        (m) => m.ContractFeatureContractListModule
      )
  },
];
```

Does anyone know, where my error is and why I see the component shortly before the login?
Thanks for answering :)

Comment: I'm not sure, as I use KC with his own interceptor, but the problem could be you are chcking permissions with an async function. Have you tried using public isAccessAllowed instead of public async isAccessAllowed?

Comment: I just tried it, no change in behavior. What do you mean with you use it with his own interceptor?

Comment: I just checked my implementation and async is correct. The only difference is in routing, I don't use canActivate. (by default interceptor I mean the KeycloakBearerInterceptor class).

Comment: What do you use for routing then? I use canActivate because KeycloakAuthGuard implements it and it's in the How-To of the library.
I also use the KeycloakBearerInterceptor for backend calls, which is activated over the option "enableBearerInterceptor: true". This is also working as it should.

Do you or anyone other have another idea what could be the error?

Comment: I made a QuickFix with an ng-container in my app-component at top-level, that is only displayed when the user is logged-in.
If someone has a better idea, please let my know.